# Korean Neo-Confucianism

Tags: confucius

What are the differences between the Neo-Confucian beliefs of Yi-Hwang ( Toi Gye)and Yi I (Yul Gok)?

I study ITF Taekwondo, and our patterns are named for significant people, places, groups, or events in Korean history. I was trying to learn more about these two men’s beliefs. The standard explanation that we are taught in Taekwondo is that Yul Gok was “nicknamed the Confucius of Korea” and that Toi Gye was a “noted scholar and expert on Neo-Confucianism”. I’m not a philosophy student and on digging deeper, the online descriptions of their teachings that I’ve found don’t make much sense to me. I need something very basic, for my own growth as well as explaining to 10 year olds why these two men are honored in our style of Taekwondo, other than what I’ve been telling them— “they were very smart men”. Thank you in advance for any help or recommended resources. :)